# Why does the VBA Excel Addin code disappears and doesn't function after I close Excel and open a new Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a simple vba addin that colors cells based on their value, and I created a function that calls it with a shortcut then I saved it as an Excel addin and added it to Excel.

The problem is the addin works fine when I add it the first time, but when I open a new Excel file, I need to disable and enable the addin for it to work.

Update: I tried it on another computer and it works, but it shows an error that when I ignore it works fine. I am adding screenshots for the error and code

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1lhE.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoazO.png)

Comment: This seems like a bug. Could you add some screenshots to your question to better help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I can't really think of a screenshot to add, it doesn't show any error message or anything. I just add and remove the add in from the developers tab

Comment: Is the addin there when you open the Visual Basic Editor?

Comment: No it isn't there when I open it

Comment: If you added the add-in correctly, you shouldnt have to add it again. Maybe explain how you added it to excel as an add-in within  your question.

Comment: I add it through developers tab then I browse for it. The thing is it works on another computer, but it shows an error: "Run Time error '91', object variable or with block variable not set. However, if I ignore the error it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Excel will open workbooks in another Excel Application. This second application can sometimes face some issues with addins. You should double-check that the new file is opened in the same Excel Application. By looking at the task manager:

[image]

In this example, I'm using Window 10 and you can see that Book3.xlsx is in a different Excel Application than Book2.xlsx and Book1.xlsx

**EDIT:**

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1103770/excel-add-ins-not-loading-since-july-2016-office-update) could also be of interest to you. The accepted answer reads:

> This problem results from security patch in KB31152, released in July 2016. According to private communication with Microsoft software engineers:
>
> "With this update, we changed the behavior of Excel so that it will
>   not load certain file types (including .xlam) when they are untrusted.
>   The easiest workaround is to find the add-in that is causing you
>   trouble, right-clicking on it in Windows Explorer, and checking
>   Unblock"
>
> An easier approach is to simply place the add-in in a Trusted Location
>   (in Excel, go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings
>   Trusted Locations), such as the following folder, and load it from there:
>
> `C:\Users\%USER NAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`

**EDIT2:**

And don't forget the option of just restarting your computer just to make sure that the problem is still there.

Comment: What I mean is that I close excel completely and open a new one so I am not sure if the this applies

Comment: @MohamedKhaled - I edited my answer to provide more suggestions. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @MohamedKhaled - Just to make sure, did you have to add the addin to the list of available addins after moving it to another folder?